# How to show full screen button in uwp win10

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, uwp

In win8 metro app, a button that can make app full screen in status bar when click it the status bar will hidden, how can show this button in Win10 uwp?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Universal App Fullscreen Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773257/windows-universal-app-fullscreen-button)

Answer (score -1):

```
ApplicationView view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
bool isInFullScreenMode = view.IsFullScreenMode;
view.TryEnterFullScreenMode();
```

Comment: Add explanation to your answer.

Comment: This doesn't add a button