# Add a button to titlebar without using XAML

Tags: c++, xaml, windows-10

I have a C++ Windows 10 app created from the MSVC template *"DirectX 11 App (Universal Windows)"*. At now, my app dos not have any .xaml files. I want to add a button to the titlebar. Corresponding to [Windows Universal App Fullscreen Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773257/windows-universal-app-fullscreen-button), I have to add something like

```
CoreApplication::GetCurrentView()->TitleBar->ExtendViewIntoTitleBar = true;
Window::Current->SetTitleBar(myTitleBar);
```

where `myTitleBar` is of class `Windows::UI::Xaml::UIElement`.

The question is how to create that `myTitleBar`. Do I have to create a xaml that defines title bar with "Fullscreen" button (and how to integrate it)? Or maybe it is possible to do it purely in C++? Or I have to recreate my app using another template *"DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows)"*?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement your application purely by DirectX, then you will need draw the buttons and text yourself, as well as to implement some basic "collision detection" to detect if the mouse was clicked inside your button when the user presses the mouse button.

However, if you want to use XAML UI elements such as Titlebar and Button together with DirectX, you must interop between XAML and DirectX, which is better to start with template "DirectX 11 and XAML App (Universal Windows)". [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) you can find detailed instruction as how to implement application with both XAML and DirectX.

Answer (score 0):

myTitleBar in defined in your xaml file.
You will have a grid named myTitleBar like this:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" x:Name="myTitleBar" Height="32">
    <!--you can customize whatever you want else in this grid-->
</Grid>
```